# Combine find file at point and find file in project

Tags: files, find-file, ffap

I'm very new to customizing Emacs, and haven't written Elisp commands before.   I'm struggling to find a command and key binding that combines `find-file-at-point` and `find-file-in-project` (or similar), perhaps a:

`M-x find-file-in-project-at-point`

such that given a file/folder structure:

```
├── main.txt
├── file1.txt
└── somepath
    └── file2.txt
```

where I'm editing `main.txt`

```
% cat main.txt
line 1 file1.txt
line 2 file2.txt
```

**and a shortcut will find `file2.txt` when my cursor is somewhere on the text of** `file2.txt` - despite it being located in `./somepath/file2.txt`.  It would be safe to assume to start the search relative to `main.txt`.  Ideally, open the file if only 1 match is found, otherwise list possible choices in minibuffer.

I have had success opening `file1.txt` from `main.txt` OK, even w/o confirmation with this pretty neat [command](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_open_file_path_fast.html).

I'm typically not dealing with a  "project" (.git) folder structures,  & folder/file structure isn't that large where an overly complex package is needed (where it might to run/index in background).

My apologies if I missed an obvious solution.

Other commands & packages functions that appear useful, but I don't have the expertise to combine them in the way I want:

- [Macro to open the file path under cursor without confirmation.](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_open_file_path_fast.html)
- [FFAP: find-file-at-point](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/FFAP.html)
- [FFIP: find-file-in-project](https://github.com/technomancy/find-file-in-project)
- [ivy, swipe, counsel](https://writequit.org/denver-emacs/presentations/2017-04-11-ivy.html)
- [projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile)
- [directory-files-recursively](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Contents-of-Directories.html)

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting idea, I never thought I need find file at point. I usually just use `expand-region.el` to select file name or partial of file path. Then `M-x find-file-in-project-by-selected`.

Any way, here is my implementation of find file at point:

```
(defun find-file-in-project-at-point (&optional open-another-window)
  "Find file whose name is guessed around point.
If OPEN-ANOTHER-WINDOW is not nil, the file will be opened in new window."
  (interactive "P")
  (let* ((filename (or (ffap-file-at-point)
                       (thing-at-point 'filename)
                       (thing-at-point 'symbol)
                       (read-string "No file name at point. Please provide file name:")))
         ;; filename could be a path
         (ffip-match-path-instead-of-filename t))
    (cond
     (filename
      ;; strip prefix "../../" or "././" from file name
      (setq filename (replace-regexp-in-string "^\\(\\.\\.*/\\)*" "" filename))
      (ffip-find-files filename open-another-window))
     (t
      (message "No file name is provided.")))))
```

Either copy this function into your `.emacs` or just upgrade `find-file-in-project` to `v5.5.0`

Comment: Perfect! This is an excellent feature. Thank you!

Comment: So this is perfect for the example in original post.  However, when the text (`main.txt`) contains a full path: `line 3 /fullpath/file3.txt`
and I select `file3.txt` it appears to search the `/fullpath/` or somewhere for awhile and then the function still didn't find the file.
  
This seems very close to being super @chenbin

Comment: Just double check. So you expect only the "file3.txt" is used as search keyword if "file.txt" is selected text, right? If you got any other requirements, raise issue at https://github.com/technomancy/find-file-in-project

Comment: Hopefully this helps:  If the cursor was on a `file.txt` - but where it is a full-path (ex. `/fullpath/file3.txt`), then I would desire the function to use that full-path first to open it.  Otherwise (if not found, or in general not a full-path),  search for file.txt based on location of `main.txt` path.   I can also add a github issue later with more detailed example.  Thanks so much for responding!

Comment: Yes, please raise an issue on github, thanks.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/technomancy/find-file-in-project/issues/97 
Thank you!